# Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a " ' ")

Tags: oracle, escaping, oracle11g

When I am trying to execute `INSERT` statement in oracle, I got `SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma` error because there is a value as `Alex's Tea Factory` in my `INSERT` statement.

How could I escape `'` ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To escape it, double the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ( 'Alex''s Tea Factory' );
```

Answer (score 13):

In SQL, you escape a quote by another quote:

```
SELECT 'Alex''s Tea Factory' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of worrying about every single apostrophe in your statement.
You can easily use the `q' Notation.`

Example

```
SELECT q'(Alex's Tea Factory)' FROM DUAL;
```

Key Components in this notation are

- `q'` which denotes the starting of the notation
- `(` an optional symbol denoting the starting of the statement to be  fully escaped.
- *Alex's Tea Factory* (Which is the statement itself)
- `)'` A closing parenthesis with a apostrophe denoting the end of the notation.

And such that, you can stuff how many apostrophes in the notation without worrying about each single one of them, they're all going to be handled safely.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Since you used `(` you must close it with `)'`, and remember it's optional to use any other symbol, for instance, the following code will run exactly as the previous one

```
SELECT q'[Alex's Tea Factory]' FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use ESCAPE like given example below

The '_' wild card character is used to match exactly one character, while '%' is used to match zero or more occurrences of any characters. These characters can be escaped in SQL.

```
SELECT name FROM emp WHERE id LIKE '%/_%' ESCAPE '/';
```

The same works inside PL/SQL:

```
 if( id like '%/_%' ESCAPE '/' )
```

This applies only to like patterns, for example in an insert there is no need to escape _ or %, they are used as plain characters anyhow. In arbitrary strings only ' needs to be escaped by ''.

Comment: Could you show how to use this in the case of an INSERT statement?

Comment: How to escape more than one more characters ? Suppose I want to select id which contains two continious _ (underscore) .

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT q'[Alex's Tea Factory]' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question implies that you're building the INSERT statement up by concatenating strings together.  I suggest that this is a poor choice as it leaves you open to SQL injection attacks if the strings are derived from user input.  A better choice is to use parameter markers and to bind the values to the markers.  If you search for `Oracle parameter markers` you'll probably find some information for your specific implementation technology (e.g. C# and ADO, Java and JDBC, Ruby and RubyDBI, etc).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way to easily escape & char in oracle DB

```
set escape '\\'
```

and within query write like

```
'ERRORS &\\\ PERFORMANCE';
```

Comment: The `set escape` command is not an Oracle SQL command. It's a command specific to the SQL*Plus tool. It is not related to the database.