# execute immediate with a variable to be passed in create statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a dynamic table where the proc_date(which is a date field) should be that of value of variable run

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dummy(lv_proc_dt VARCHAR2) AS

  select_s  VARCHAR2(30000);
  v_sysdate VARCHAR2(10) := to_char(to_date('MAY-2016', 'MON-YYYY'), 'mONyy');

BEGIN

  select_s := 'CREATE TABLE msi_fund_thrshld_acct_BD_' || v_sysdate ||
              ' AS select *  from msi_funding_threshold_account2 where proc_dt=TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('01 - '||LV_PROC_DT ),' dd - mon - yyyy ')))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select_s;
END;

exec dummy('MAY-2016');
```

But getting below error:

> `Error(8,163): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "01" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset`

Comment: Hi Hawabi, consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Thanx J.Chomel .Wil keep in mind.Please kindly help

Comment: Its getting more accurate. The `''` should be an improvement. Use `dbms_output.put_line(select_s)` to debug before passing it to execute immediate.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DUMMY(LV_PROC_DT VARCHAR2) AS

  select_s VARCHAR2(30000); 
  v_sysdate VARCHAR2(10) := to_char(to_date('MAY-2016', 'MON-YYYY'),'mONyy');

BEGIN
  SELECT_S := 'CREATE TABLE msi_fund_thrshld_acct_BD_'||V_SYSDATE
            ||  ' AS select * from msi_funding_threshold_account2 where proc_dt=TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(''01-''||LV_PROC_DT ),''DD-MON-YYYY'')))'; 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select_s;
END;
```

Can be called this way from `sqlplus`

```
EXEC DUMMY('MAY-2016');
```

Comment: what change did u make?i am still getting the same error!!

Comment: for hawabi: he added double quoting, that is what you were missing; did you try it? @Praneeth: while answering, it's a good practice adding some explanation to the code.  to both: try to better format your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line break. Oracle won't understand your line break, so you need to remove it or [concatenate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) smaller strings together:

```
-- [...]

BEGIN

  select_s := 'CREATE TABLE msi_fund_thrshld_acct_BD_' || v_sysdate ||
              ' AS select *  from msi_funding_threshold_account2 where proc_dt=TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(' ||
              '''01 - ''||LV_PROC_DT ),'' dd - mon - yyyy '')))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select_s;
END;
```

or

```
  select_s := 'CREATE TABLE msi_fund_thrshld_acct_BD_' || v_sysdate ||
              ' AS select *  from msi_funding_threshold_account2 where proc_dt=TRUNC(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(''01 - ''||LV_PROC_DT ),'' dd - mon - yyyy '')))';
```

Also added double quotes `''` as pointed out in @Praneeth's answer: you need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11717159/2752041) your quotes since your query is a string to be parsed.

Comment: I believe the only problem is the bad quoting; line breaks in dynamic string should not be a problem.

Comment: Mathielo could be right... But hawabi did changes to the OP, and I intervened in the process, we can't really say.