# Why is my concatenation not allowing me to append a % to the end?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO E_COUNT FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE CONCAT(UPPER("example"), "%");
```

I am getting the following error

```
ORA-00904: "%": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 111
```

Comment: '%' is a special character so you need to escape it in a string, this question tells you how to do that: [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a " ' ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717159/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a)

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. table and column names) if you need them. Single quotes for string literals.

Comment: What the message says is that you don't have a column called `%` in any table or view. Literal strings must be single-quoted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use double quotes, it is interpreted as an identifier.

```
with t ("ab", "%") as (
select 1, 2 from dual
)
select concat("ab", "%") from t;

CO
--
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO E_COUNT FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER('example%');
```

or if you're comparison is to a bind variable, then like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO E_COUNT FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER(:V_EXAMPLE)||'%';
```

Use single quotes (double quotes are for labels, not literal values), and just put the wildcard right in with the text.

Comment: I am eventually going to be replacing example with a parameter. So you're saying :ParameterName

Comment: Exact syntax (with or without leading colon : ) depends on whether the parameter is initialized in the code or passed in as a procedure input, but either way use ||'%' to append the wildcard to the parameter value.